# Copy and Rename files in destination folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to copy my files to a new destination using **fs** and then rename them to like 1.png , 1.txt and so on but i always get an error here is my code :

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')

const dir = 'files/newFiles'
const fileNames = fs.readdirSync('files')

for(let i = 0 ; i < fileNames.length ; i++) {

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        if(!fs.existsSync(dir+'/image')) fs.mkdirSync(dir+'/image');
        if(!fs.existsSync(dir+'/txt')) fs.mkdirSync(dir+'/txt');
    }
    const ext = path.extname(fileNames[i])
    if(ext === '.png') return fs.copyFileSync(fileNames[i], dir+'/image/'+i+ext)
    if(ext === '.txt') return fs.copyFileSync(fileNames[i], dir+'/txt/'+i+ext)
}
```

here is the error message :

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, copyfile 'file1.png' -> 'files/newFiles/image/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my answer.
The mistake is just slash and back slash and the `fs.copyFileSync()` function.

The first parameter should be the filepath.
but here in script, it is just filename such as "111.png" where should be such as "C:\files\111.png".

So the solution is that

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')

const dir = 'files\\newFiles'
const fileNames = fs.readdirSync('files')

for (let i = 0 ; i < fileNames.length ; i++) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);

    if (!fs.existsSync(dir+'\\image'))
      fs.mkdirSync(dir+'\\image');
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir+'\\txt'))
      fs.mkdirSync(dir+'\\txt');
  }
  const ext = path.extname(fileNames[i])
  if (ext === '.png')
    return fs.copyFileSync(
      __dirname + "\\files\\" + fileNames[i],
      dir + '\\image\\' + i + ext
    )
  if (ext === '.txt')
    return fs.copyFileSync(
      __dirname + "\\files\\" + fileNames[i],
      dir + '\\txt\\' + i + ext
    )
}
```

Please check it

Comment: still the same error , i don't know why 

Comment: I think you need to indicate the dir as this. const dir = __dirname + "files\\newFiles" there's no way to know directory without driver path or something like that.

Comment: i tried this but still not working , i dont know why , when i use if(!existSync(dir)) it says its there but when i run the for loop it stops working

Comment: yes the script and files folder inside the same main directory

http://epvpimg.com/j0nAbab

Comment: Got it. The problem is definetly that "return fs.copyFileSync("files\\"+fileNames[i], dir+'\\image\\'+i+ext" , because fileNames[i] should be the filepath, not the filename.

Comment: yea you were right i changed it to this and its working now 

fs.copyFileSync( __dirname +"/files/" + fileNames[i], dir +'/image/'+ i + ext);

Comment: You shouldn't be hardcoding (back)slashes, for this very reason. Now the "fixed" code will crash on Linux and Mac. That's what `path.join` is for. (e.g. `path.join(__dirname, 'files', fileNames[i])`)